Genetic distance, different surnames
I see that in talking about genetic distance between two Y-DNA, STR test results frequently use the phrase "having the same surname", or some similar phrase. Why? "Illegitimate" offspring frequently have different surnames. My 111-marker FTDNA Y-DNA match list currently includes no other person with the same surname, but does include matches with 0 genetic distance.

Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! I'm not clear on exactly what question you're asking here.  There are many more reasons for Y-DNA matches to not have matching surnames than illegitimacy.  In one of his webinars, Genetic Genealogist Maurice Gleeson listed many social reasons that people might change their surname.  His calculation (which he described as a back-of-the-envelope estimate) was that a Y-DNA project is likely to only have 50% of the people in the project sharing the main surname in the project.

Are you really Asking why STR test results frequently use the phrase 'having the same surname', please?
If not, what?

Having matches at Y-111 with 0 genetic distance is a very good result. The YDNA results are a good tool to help work toward finding out where surname variances may have first occurred and possibly how and why. Such variances are not uncommon. Looking at Y-67 may possibly yield even more matches who can potentially be contacted so that collaboration and tree comparison can lead to answers.
